# why does Rc works in async fn

Tags: asynchronous, rust

I found this example compile successfully, but isn't Rc<> thread unsafe? What if tikio start multi thread to execute test fn, won't it cause Rc to run on different threads?

```
use std::rc::Rc;
use tokio::join;
use std::time;
use async_std::task::{sleep};



async fn test(t:Rc<String>){
    let k = t;
    println!("1. test,{:?}", k);
    sleep(time::Duration::from_secs(1)).await;
    println!("2. test,{:?}", k);
}


#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let r = Rc::new("abc".to_string());
    let f1 = test(r.clone());
    let f2 = test(r.clone());
    join!(f1,f2);
}
```

Comment: According to [the docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/), "As a result, the Rust compiler will check at compile time that you are not sending Rcs between threads." If that code compiles, it seems like you're not "sending Rcs between threads" and that code is memory safe. I'm not 100% confident in this, I'm just going based on the docs and you saying that this code compiles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bit nuanced, but `#[tokio::main]` will rewrite your `async main()` into something like this:

```
fn main() {
    tokio::runtime::Builder::new_multi_thread()
        .enable_all()
        .build()
        .unwrap()
        .block_on(async {
            // your code from `async main()`
        })
}
```

The last step that actually runs everything, [`.block_on()`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/runtime/struct.Runtime.html#method.block_on), does *not* require the given task to be thread-safe (a.k.a. implement `Send`) because it will not be ran on a separate thread, even when using the multi-threaded executor:

> This runs the given future on the current thread, blocking until it is complete, and yielding its resolved result.

Other tokio utilities and any spawned tasks may be ran on separate threads, and even move between them, but not the initial task.